# AWK - how to get contents of a file pointed by first column of a file

Tags: awk

I have a file f1.txt which has contents like below

```
file1 file2
file3 file4
```

and file1 has contents like below

```
student1 10
student2 20
```

Now I want to get the first column from f1.txt and print out contents of file1 using awk.
I tried `awk '{print $1}' f1.txt | cat $1`, but it doesn't work.
Any simple way to get the contents of file1 using `awk`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within `awk` you can call function `system` to run external command:

```
awk '{system("cat "$1)}' f1.txt
```

Or if you want to print only content of the `file1` and not `file3`:

```
awk 'NR==1{system("cat "$1)}' f1.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are not doing any processing of the data within awk, and using awk just to select the data, this is suited to xargs, e.g.,

```
awk '{ print $1; }' | xargs cat
```

That has the advantage over `system` that xargs will collect multiple parameters for cat, and thus be a little more efficient.